# Reverse a number without making it a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reverse

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong in my code please? I'm trying to reverse a number without changing it to a string. I've been searching google and looked through the previous questions asked about this topic and from what I can see my code mirrors the other answers.

I've only been able to find code in Java, C, or C++ that do not use the to string method.

In my attempts, when I run the code in the browser console it either gives me an answer of "Infinity" or crashes my browser.

Here's my code...

```js
function reverseNumber(number) {

  var revNumber = 0;

  while (number > 0) {
    revNumber = (revNumber * 10) + (number % 10);
    number = number / 10;
  }

  return revNumber;
}

console.log(reverseNumber(876));
```

I know it must be some small syntax error but I just don't see it. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean make the number negative? Or reverse the order?

Comment: [Formula for reversing digits of positive integer `n`](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/472981)

Comment: Syntax error means that your [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) _says_ “`SyntaxError`”. Yours is a _semantical_ error, not a syntactical one.

Comment: change to  `number = parseInt(number / 10);`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`number = number / 10;` inside a `while` loop whose condition is `number > 0` means that `number` will only reach 0 after a very large number of iterations, once number precision fails. (eg. 876 => 87.6 => 8.76 => .876 => .0876...) That's not what you want. You might divide by 10 *and* drop the decimal part:

```js
function reverseNumber(number) {
  var revNumber = 0;
  while (number > 0) {
    revNumber = (revNumber * 10) + (number % 10);
    number = Math.floor(number / 10);
  }
  return revNumber;
}
console.log(reverseNumber(876));
```

Comment: Does not work if number ends with zero. ex: `10`.

Comment: Up to OP to clarify, but I would think that, eg, 6780 -> 0876 === 876 - the desired output is a number, not a string, and numbers can't have leading 0s. (I can't think of what other option there would be...?)

Comment: Awesome! I didn't realize it behaves like an asymptote, but it makes sense now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Andres That doesn't make much sense. `-321` can't turn into `123-`.. unless you want to coerce it to a string first. `[...String(num)].reverse().join('')`

Answer (score 3):

These works.

**Basic Implementation**:

```js
function reverse(n)
{
    var temp=0;
    while(n)
    {
        temp *= 10;
        temp += n%10;
        n = Math.floor(n/10);
    }
    return temp;
}

console.log(reverse(123))
console.log(reverse(456))
console.log(reverse(789))
console.log(reverse(7890))
```

**Inline Basic implementation**:

```js
function reverse(n)
{
    var reverse=0;
    while(n>0) (reverse=reverse*10+n%10, n=Math.floor(n/10));
    return reverse;
}

console.log(reverse(123))
console.log(reverse(456))
console.log(reverse(789))
console.log(reverse(7890))
```

Implementation using **arrays**.

```js
function reverse(n)
{
    var arr=[], reverse=0;
    while(n>0) (arr.push(n%10), n=Math.floor(n/10));
    while(arr.length) reverse=reverse*10+arr.shift();
    return reverse;
}

console.log(reverse(123))
console.log(reverse(456))
console.log(reverse(789))
console.log(reverse(7890))
```

Comment: You might as well use `Math.floor` instead of `parseInt`. `parseInt` is for converting strings to numbers.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: After reading the suggestion to use parseInt my next question was if they differ in use. I learned 2 things tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
number = Math.floor(number / 10);
```

You need to Math.floor as `number = number / 10`; will give in floating points value which will always be greater than 0

```js
   function reverseNumber(number) {

          var revNumber = 0;

          console.log("######### steps ###########");

          while (number > 0) {
            console.log("Step " , number);
            revNumber = (revNumber * 10) + (number % 10);
            number = Math.floor(number / 10);
          }
            console.log("######### steps End ###########");

          return revNumber;
        }

        console.log(reverseNumber(876));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function reverseNumber(number) {

  var revNumber = 0;

  while (number > 0) {
    revNumber = (revNumber * 10) + (number % 10);
    number = Math.floor(number / 10);
  }

  return revNumber;
}

console.log(reverseNumber(876));
```

El problema estaba en la reeasignación del valor del number, con el Math.floor sacamos la parte entera y solo esta, asi evitamos los decimales.

Answer (score -3):

```
function reverseInt(int) {
  return  parseInt(int.toString().split('').reverse().join(''))
}
console.log(reverseInt(510));
```